# Лучшая клавиатура для программиста?

Tags: клавиатура

Здравствуйте!
История такая. Старая клавиатура померла три месяца назад, к новой никак не могу приноровиться. Решил сделать себе подарок в виде отличной клавиатуры. Но, вдоволь начитавшись форумов, понял, что дело это не из легких.
Для себя сделал два вывода: клавиатура должна быть механической, тип механизма - [Cherry-MX Blue](http://www.keyboardshop.ru/page/keyswitch)

Но и таких клавиатур предостаточно:

- iOne Scorpius M10
- iOne Scorpius M10 BL
- Ducky DK-9008
- Ducky DK-9000
- Ducky DK-1008
- Ducky DK-1087
- Ducky DK-9008-G2
- Cherry G80-3000 LSCRC-2
- iOne Scorpius 35
- Das Model S

Выскажите пожалуйста своё мнение, свои предпочтения по данному вопросу, какими клавиатурами пользовались и какие понравились. Буду очень рад, если мнения будут подкреплены опытом. Скажу честно, на ощупь не трогал ни одну из таких клавиатур и у друзей таких нет. Что касается магазинов, то в них обычно дешевые мембранные клавиатуры.

P.S.: Почему я задаю такой вопрос здесь, а не на форумах? Во-первых, считаю, что здесь собрано большое количество программистов, готовых делится своим мнением и не боятся высказываться. Во-вторых, есть система голосования за ответы, можно понять не только мнение автора ответа, но и сколько человек поддерживают его мысли.

Comment: Круто! Я и не знал про такое (это я ссылочку почитал). 

Для себя я не так давно обнаружил, что **очень удобна** клавиатура с подсветкой символов на клавишах.

Comment: Подсветка нафиг не нужна. Все программеры набирают текст вслепую!

Comment: Подсветка как раз полезна. Это символы на клавишах практически бесполезны.

Правда, с другой стороны, подсветка полезна очень редко. Если ситуация такова, что она требуется — значит нужно устранять проблемы с освещением рабочего места, а не портить глаза. Если, конечно, дело не сводится к ситуации класса «надо быстро посмотреть и идти дальше.»

Comment: >  проблемы с освещением рабочего места, а не портить глаза

Согласен. Наш глаз более приспособлен к отраженному свету, чем к источникам, которыми будут являться кнопочки с подсветкой. Хотя это может быть красиво. Но программисту ведь важнее функционал

>Это символы на клавишах практически бесполезны.

не согласен. Ситуация 1. За компьютер садится человек, не умеющий набирать вслепую. Ситуация 2. Нужно ввести пароль... Я обычно ввожу вслепую, но наличие надписей на кнопках помогает... Тем более, если нужно ввести русское слово или фразу в латинской раскладке (типа "dxfof[.uf;bk,skwbnhec")

Comment: ответ на вопрос: удобная. Уже ж не дети и знаем что самых лучших (а тем более для программистов(а чем кстати программисты в плане удобства отличаются от бухгалтеров?)) не бывает.

Comment: Ну, то, что человек, не умеющий набирать вслепую (причем на Двораковской раскладке), не сядет за мою машину — это еще не факт, что плохо. Наоборот, прекрасная отмазка — и жлобом не прослыл, и попользоваться не дал. ;)

Но, вообще, да, согласен, есть такой аспект.

Comment: @Viacheslav, наверное, разница в том, что программисты задействуют ВСЮ клавиатуру, а бухгалтера - только цифровую часть... Вы бы еще про секретарей или переводчиков вспомнили...

Comment: Господи! Как хорошо, что меня не клинит еще и по таким вопросам, а то на человеческую жизнь вообще б не хватило времени. ))) Свой первый код я набирал на БК0010, так там, то по чём стучишь, даже клавиатурой назвать трудно. И ничего, как-то справлялся.

Comment: А мне вот интересно, как эти Черри чистить. Ибо если работать дома, то там есть всякая шерстяная живность, которая и подрыхнуть на клавиатуре не против :) И вообще, + к @Deonis. Меня вполне устраивают тыркалки за 100-200 рублей, а первый код набирался на СМ1800 :-)

Comment: @klopp Терминалы на СМ1800 имели герконные пары, там шерсть на контакты попасть не могла.

Comment: Ну, они и стояли там, где зверей не было (на станции юных техников, а не дома).

Comment: СЮТ -- это интересно. У нас они шли в составе АРМов на СМ-1420. Для управления диджитайзерами...

Answer (score 9):

Клавиатуру нужно выбирать по тактильным ощущениям.
То есть взять и по клацать, если приятно на ощупь можно брать если нет то не стоит.

а механизм это уже второстепенно, может быть мембранная и работать на ней удобно а может быть механическая и чувствовать дискомфорт.

Так же брать желательно полноформатную, с нормальным размером клавиш.

Боле весомо правильное положение рук и положение кисти руки.
Так как больше устают сами руки и кисти при длительной работе за клавиатурой нежели пальцы.
Так же желательно стул с подлокотниками чтобы локти не весели в воздухе когда работаешь, и обязательно раз в час делать разминку для пальцев.

ЗЫ Провожу за компьютером больше 10 часов в день из них 5-6 пишу, советы из своего опыта, конкретную клавиатуру советовать дело не благодарное :)

Answer (score 3):

Ms natural 4000 на работе стоит, работаю программистом c#/java, обожаю эту клавиатуру

Answer (score 2):

Вариантов несколько. На практике я работал за следующими, которые могу порекомендовать:

1. IBM Model M. Посмотреть можно [здесь](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8thH3EoIGx4), [здесь](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rd9DkghjXTE) и [здесь](http://windsor-on.canadianlisted.com/computer-parts/wtb-ibm-lexmark-model-m5-1-1370478-keyboard-with-trackball_649951.html). Адская, мегаудобная штука. Минусы: нет кнопок Win и контекстного меню (этих кнопок в 87 году быть не могло просто). Еще она громкая. Плюсы - отличный ход клавиш, четкий клик, длинный и качественный хвост. Самое главное - колпачки съемные (!) и клаву легко локализовать при наличии нужных колпачков.
2. IBM Notebook keyboard. Идеальная как на ноутбуках ThinkPad T40(p)/T41(p)/T42(p)/T43(p) и T60(p)/T61(p). Также они ставились вплоть до T500/R500. Лучше если с механизмом от NMB (было еще два производителя, вроде lexmark и chicony). Существует и в виде отдельной [клавиатуры](http://www.thinkscopes.com/thinkpad-usb-keyboard-with-trackpoint/). Плюсы - удобно, в комплекте с "мышкой". У отдельной - интерфейс USB + встроенный хаб. У обеих вариаций (в ноуте и отдельно) - четкий, ясный клик.
3. [Mitsumi keyboard millenium](http://market.yandex.ru/model.xml?modelid=734716&hid=723088). Кнопки мембранные. Клик мягкий. Супруга в восторге, а я лично не очень  - терпимо. Клава практически не слышна. Подвергалась неоднократным залитиям, падениям, жена по ней фигачила ножом. Клава до сих жива.

Еще поглядите обязательно [Хабр](http://habrahabr.ru/post/86240/)

Comment: Спасибо большое за ссылки. Большая беда в том, что их практически не найти. Только последнюю смог найти в продаже. Сам только, что вернулся из магазина. Нашел пару механических: Razer BlackWidow и Razer BlackWidow Ultimate. Очень понравились, не мог оторваться от печатанья выдуманных текстов) Правда, то, как я набирал, слышали все вокруг. Не знаю как к ней отнесутся мои соседи) А как ваших клавиатур с громкостью клика?

Comment: у 1 - громко. у 2 - терпимо, если сидеть в другом конце комнаты от других людей. 3 - почти не слышно.

Comment: > Большая беда в том, что их практически не найти. 

[ebay][1]? Но за 100 долларов, конечно, покупать такую клавиатуру неразумно.

[1]:http://www.ebay.com/itm/Brand-New-genuine-IBM-vintage-Model-M-French-keyboard-1378177-FRU-1378178-/130827330496?pt=PCA_Mice_Trackballs&hash=item1e75eaa3c0

Answer (score 1):

Использую тонкую мембранную клавиатуру с разъёмами USB, Mini-Jack, MIC и дополнительными мультимедийными клавишами A4Tech KLS-7MU Silver PS/2. На ней клавиши основного блока расположены слегка "ёлочкой", поэтому запястья при работе находятся в правильном положении. Занимаюсь программированием на Java, PHP, а также веб-разработкой, не отказываю себе в удовольствии провести часок-другой за какой-нибудь игрушкой - никаких проблем, дискомфорта. Клаве третий год уже.

Answer (score 0):

Если печатаете "вслепую" то имеет место выбирать клавиатуру с привычным для вас расположением кнопок, если нет то воспользуйтесь методом предложенным [@savro](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/8523/savro)

Comment: Если нет, то имеет смысл потратить некоторое количество времени на обучение.

Comment: я пробовал у меня не получается. использую клавиатуры только с кнопкой левого слеша перед забоем и нормальным enterом

Answer (score 0):

Сегодня заказал [такую](http://www.getdigital.eu/Das-Keyboard-Model-S.html). Говорят что мега удобная, только достать не просто. Через полчаса гугления на хабре случайно выцепил ссылку на [магазин](http://geekboards.ru/), там и заказал.